# How to load a file without waiting for COMPLETE event?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Certainly it is not the best practice, but I need to load a file and get its contents within the same function call. That is calling the `urlLoader.load` function and then waiting (say with an `while(true)`) for the contents to load.

I am stuck with the fact that flash will not trigger events nor continue with the file loading until the current thread finishes. Is there any way to allow flash to make the file contents available without exiting the current method call.

On a side note, I know this is not a good thing to do. This is only for easing a process in a local environment in which I need the file contents without waiting for an event. If I let the process continue other events already queued will fire and becomes a mess. Sadly refactoring the code to wait altogether would be too much effort.

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't have written your code in a bad way in the first place. Just suck it up and refactor.

Comment: IMHO, no way. Loading is done with system code, which will not start until user code finished. Search for 'elastic racetrack' to see what happens during the flash frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can get around this is to embed the file in the SWF itself with `[Embed]`.

If you want to load the file at run-time, then you have to use events.  All I/O is done with an asynchronous pattern.  Embrace it and you'll write very efficient code.

Comment: Just to further add to the answer, since I was trying to load a text file, a link on how this are handled by the `[Embed]` tag: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Embed_external_text_or_Javascript_in_an_Actionscri-12749.html

Answer (score 1):

try [`flash.net.URLStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html)

Comment: This is still asynchronous, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ Samuel Neff - the question is `How to load a file without waiting for COMPLETE event?`

Comment: @www0z0k, so how does this answer that?  If you use `URLStream` you still have to wait for `URLStream`'s `COMPLETE` event before you can process the loaded file.

Comment: @ Samuel Neff - *The URLStream class provides low-level access to downloading URLs. Data is made available to application code immediately as it is downloaded, instead of waiting until the entire file is complete as with URLLoader. The URLStream class also lets you close a stream before it finishes downloading. The contents of the downloaded file are made available as raw binary data.* - a quote from the link

Comment: Is certainly does not depend on the COMPLETE event to read the data, but still the load does not begin in the current stack call.

Comment: @www0z0k, LopSae was asking about making the call and then in the same function reading the data without listening to events or using a continuation.  `URLStream` **does not provide this functionality**.